# @Value annotation not resolved

Tags: java, spring, maven, annotations, javabeans

I'm creating a sample project as mentioned in [MKyong's tutorial.](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-el-hello-world-example/) I am using eclipse. When I created the project, I could not find any way to write a `@Value` annotation.

I know it seems stupid, but I am not able to solve this problem at all. Can you please help?

```
...
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component ("newSession")
public class Session implements DisposableBean, InitializingBean {

    @Value ("3232")
    private int id;
...
```

pom.xml:

```xml
...
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
....
```

Apologies for the bad indentation (lots of copy-paste) and the silly question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Original Answer:**

The `@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value` annotation can be found in the spring-beans jar. Adding the following dependency to your pom should fix the problem:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**Update:**

I believe the problem is simply a classpath issue. The dependency `org.springframework:spring:2.5.6`, also has the package `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation`, but without the `Value` annotation class. My presumption is that the eclipse classpath is mucked up. If you update the classpath (i.e. mvn eclipse:eclipse) your problem should be resolved.

Also do you need the old Spring dependency? If not then it is probably best to remove it.

As an aside, @BalajiV is absolutely correct you don't need an explicit dependency to `spring-beans` as it will be pulled in transiently via the `spring-context` dependency. Have to admit that personally if I have a compile time dependency to a class from a specific jar (in this case the `Value` class) then I always explicitly define a dependency to that jar in my pom instead of relying on another 3rd party dependency to provide it for me. I know it is unlikely to happen but if in a future release of `spring-context` they remove the dependency to `spring-beans` then my module would no longer work when I upgraded to the newer version.

Comment: Yes, 2.5.6 is the bothering package. Now how do I solve the issuea? `mvn eclipse:eclipse` isn't solving the problem.

Comment: Why do you need the org.springframework:spring:2.5.6 dependency? Can you not simply remove it completely from your pom? Does the project build outside of Eclipse (i.e. from the command line, does `mvn install` work?) From within Eclipse have you tried refreshing (Right click on the project and select Refresh) and cleaning (Project -> Clean...) the project?

Comment: Well, I removed it and it works. Apparently my copy-paste work from mkyong's site caused the problem - it's a bit outdated.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** necessary to have **spring-beans** mentioned as a separate dependency in **pom.xml** if we have **spring-context** mentioned in it. This will take care of downloading many spring related jars and one among them is **spring-beans** which is what we need to use **@Value** annotation.

Regarding your problem, is it a compilation error on the @Value line or is the value not being injected to your variable? I am asking you this question because your code snippet works fine on my example maven project in eclipse with the same pom.xml that you have given here.

Comment: The error is during compilation. Yes, even I thought it was enough to have spring-context mentioned in pom.xml.

Comment: @SiddharthaRT, I have updated my answer. I believe something is wrong with your classpath due to the org.springframework:spring:2.5.6 dependency, as it contains the org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation package but without the Value class. Which would explain why you are getting a compile error stating that Value can't be found.

Additionally how are you building your module? You could try building outside of eclipse (from a console, mvn clean install should do the trick) to see if it is successful there.

Comment: Which other version of spring can I use?